# Prevent FreeMarker to wrap a class implementing Collection in SimpleSequence

Tags: freemarker

I have a `Page` class implementing `java.util.Collection` as well as other methods like `hasPreviousPage`, `getTotalPages`, etc. Freemarker wraps this class in a `SimpleSequence`. That will hide the methods not part of `java.util.Collection`.

i.e. when I write `${page.getTotalPages()}` I got this error:

> Expected hash. *myPage* evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleSequence [...]

How can I tell Freemarker to expose both the methods to iterate over the *Collection*, so that code such `<#list page as item>` will keep on working, and the custom ones?

Thanks for any suggestion/reference.

Comment: I found a PARTIAL SOLUTION Googling around: if the data-object is wrapped in a BeanModel all the methods of the original object are accessible, although the object will not be recognized as iterable.

So, 

    import freemarker.ext.beans.BeanModel;
    import freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper;

    Page page = dao.getObjects(); 
    Map map = new Map();
    map.put("myPage", new BeanModel(page, BeansWrapper.getDefaultInstance());

then map is passed to the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** you can't or shouldn't change that class... you can extend the DefaultObjectWrapper or BeansWrapper so that it treats some of the classes specially. DefaultObjectWrapper itself is an example of doing that (it wraps DOM objects and Jython objects specially). You could warp the object with BeanModel, but add an extra sub-variable called "items" which returns the same object but wrapped into SimpleSeqence. Then you just configure FreeMarker to use your custom ObjectWrapper globally (Configuration.setObjectWrapper) and you don't have to touch the application code anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Two thoughts, although neither one answers your question (which seems quite sensible).

1) I think instead of `${page.totalPages}` you could use `${page.getTotalPages()}`.

2) Consider whether it makes sense for `Page` to *contain* a collection object (so you'd use `<#list page.items as item>`) rather than implementing Collection, which is a smidgen unusual if you're not actually creating a new collection data structure.

Comment: 1) Yes, I should have called getTotalPages(), fixing the question now.

2) I agree, but that class is already used elsewhere, so I was considering to try to expose it as-is in the model before start a refactoring.

BTW I just found the way FreeMarker can expose any method of the wrapped object. That is using the BeansWrapper wrapper instead of the DefaultObjectWrapper.